# MySQL connection very slow with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, iis

I am timing a simple query using PHP's `microtime(true)` function before and after. The query is `SELECT NOW()` and the execution time is 0.015625 seconds which is believe to be **15 milliseconds** - this is far too long for such a basic query!

I know there is definitely something wrong with my setup, but I cannot seem to fix it.

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit with PHP 5.4, MySQL 5.6 Server and IIS 7.5.

I have tried changing the host name to 127.0.0.1 and adding code to the hosts file, as well as modifying php.ini and my.ini - nothing seems to speed it up.

Comment: I think there are too many variables in your benchmark. PHP and IIS I think they add more time in order to process your requests and show the results, and I don't believe PHP is very precise calculating the execution of the query using something like a timer. If you want to measure the execution time of a query, I think you should consider [profiling it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html), obviously stopping all other activities executing in MySQL before doing that. In this way, you will have a more detailed and precise result according to the SQL engine.

Comment: Thank you for that. When I profile that in MySQL I get 0.0000 seconds. That is why it is something to do with my connection between PHP and MySQL, not the query itself.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I think PHP and IIS are most likely the problem. Since you're executing everything locally, you're using the an IP address instead of a machine name and you're already tweaked your configuration files, I believe there's nothing else you can improve..Maybe [this article](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2008/11/02/php-performance-on-windows-2008iis7/) could help you. Did you try to [disable DNS host name lookups](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/host-cache.html) using `--skip-name-resolve`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried what you suggested, but not having any luck with anything. I'm frustrated because clearly lots of people are having similar problems and then it is being fixed quite easily, yet none of these seem to work for me.

Comment: If you are aiming for a "production" system, and this timing is worrying you, then I suggest you move away from Windows and IIS.  Unix+Apache+PHP is quite workable.  And, if you get into the big leagues, you will have your web servers separate from your mysql servers; that is, 'localhost' will no longer be an option.